# Can I stay for 5 months as a visitor in the UK? (+ complicated situation)

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, study

I'm Korean and a Master's student in the UK.
However, my situation is quite complicated.
My course started on Sep in 2017 and was supposed to finish the next year.
But I took a semester off due to my health issue and want to return for my final project. And my school, in this situation, cannot provide me with any support for visa.

My school suggests me return to the UK without visa since I can legally stay there up to 6 months as a traveler. The thing is, it hasn't been even a year since I came back to Korea from the UK. A person at the boarder control will doubt my purpose of stay due to lack of solid proof from my school, and such a long period of stay for travel(because I'll be a traveler without visa).

I really need to do research in the UK for my dissertation...
I didn't even imagine I wouldn't have a student visa for return...
(The last time I talked with my school, they seemed very supportive for my return. It turned out they didn't know my situation in detail at the time.)

I don't even know whether I can say a student as my occupation because I'm visiting the UK as a traveler. It might be confusing if I say I haven't graduated from a university in the UK, which means I'm a student THERE, but coming back as a visitor? It doesn't sound right...
Then... my jobless situation could cause more problems.

There is something I personally can show the person at the boarder.

1. My student ID (But this is for school year of 2017/18.)
2. My bank account from Santander with money for 5 months of stay.
3. My credit card that I can use in other countries (VISA)
4. My school account (I can access to school portal and the like.)
5. Receipt of rental fee for housing (student accommodation)
6. Return ticket that proves I'm leaving the UK in 5 months
7. DPD form I submitted to school for interruptions of studies (But the school doesn't recommend me do so since the situation can become more complicated.)
8. I'll tell the person I'm planning to pursue a PhD, and that's why I don't have a job currently, which is true.

---

Is there anything I can add more?

I have some friends who are still studying in the UK if this can be helpful..

Comment: Why can't you get a student visa?

Comment: Immigration does not care about your **complicated** situation. In their eyes everyone has a sob story. Whatever you plan/hope to do, stay within the rules. Your story seems convoluted and if I were the immigration officer I would likely send you back on the next flight. Sounds very strange your shook will not support you with the right paperwork. So you’re going to school for a masters program on a visitor visa. Bizarre

Answer (score 5):

The Immigration Rules V App 3 (25) allow visitors carry out the following:

(a) educational exchanges or visits with a state funded school or academy or independent school; or

(b) a maximum of 30 days study on:
(i) recreational courses (not English language training);
(ii) a short-course (which includes English language training) at an accredited institution;
provided that the main purpose of the visit is not to study and the study is not at a state funded school or academy.
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Your school is giving you very bad advice. You need to apply for a student visa.

Comment: Truly bizarre. The university is risking their Tier 4 licence by telling a student to do this.

Comment: +1 Most of the documentation mentioned in the question is likely to convince immigration that the OP's primary purpose and activity is study for several months.